# Spring controller with error for return a output to the view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In some methods from the controllers in my spring application, I have methods which return a String value to the view, like this example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra_campo", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String cadastra_campo(@ModelAttribute("username") String username, @RequestParam("nome") String campo) {
    if(key.temAutorizacao(key.getUsuarioByUsername(username).getId())) {
        if(key.cadastra(campo))
            return "yes";
        else
            return "not";
    }
    else {
        return "no_permit";
    }
}
```

But, monitoring the value received by the views, through the browser's console, I realize that all of them are trying reach out pages like /jst/yes.jsp.

this output is read in the view by jquery functions like that:

```
$("#incluir_campo").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/key/cadastra_campo"/>",
        data: {nome: $("input[name=nome_campo]").val() }
    }).done(function(data){
        if(data=="yes") {
            var newRow = $("<tr>");

            cols = 'td> <input type="text" name="${item_key.nome}" value="${item_key.nome}"> </td>';
            cols += '<td> <button type="button" id="excluir_campo_${item_campo.id}" class="btn btn-link">Excluir</button> </td>';

            newRow.append(cols);
            $("table.campos").append(newRow);
            $("input[name=nome_campo]").reset();
        }
        else {
            alert("erro ao incluir campo");
        }
    }).fail(function(){
        alert("falha ao incluir campo");
    });
});
```

I am using a java configuration in replacement to files web.xml and spring-servlet.xml, through this classes:

**WebAppInitializer.java**

```
@Order(value=1)
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
      // Create the 'root' Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      rootContext.register(WebAppConfig.class);

      // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
      //container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

      // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

      // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

**WebAppConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.PROXY, proxyTargetClass=true)
@ComponentScan(value="com.horariolivre")
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/bootstrap/**").addResourceLocations("/bootstrap/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/extras/**").addResourceLocations("/extras/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/jquery/**").addResourceLocations("/jquery/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

Someone knows how to do for my views receive correctly a String value, instead of try reach a jsp page?

Comment: Annotate your methods with `@ResponseBody`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't provide a `ViewResolver` in your context configuration available to the `DispatcherServlet`, it will use a default. That default is an `InternalResourceViewResolver`.

When your `@RequestMapping` handler method returns a `String`, Spring uses `ViewNameMethodReturnValueHandler` to handle it. It will set the returned `String` value as the request's view name. Down the line, Spring's `DispatcherServlet` will use the `InternalResourceViewResolver` to resolve a view based on the provided name. This will be a JSP. It will then forward to that JSP.

If you want to return the handler method's `String` return value as the body of the HTTP response, annotate the method with `@ResponseBody`. Spring will use `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` to write the value to the `HttpServletResponse` `OutputStream`.